# how to summon layered snow in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am making a map and I would like to layer snow on top of each other, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with a command block. What I would like it look like after the command has run is a staircase of layered snow that you can walk up.[image: a stair-case]

anyone know the command to do this?
FYI I know you can just spawn snow above the main snow block and let it drop down, but that would just be unrealistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create a staircase of snow with one command, because each individual block would have different properties (namely the `layers` property, in Minecraft Java). By using multiple command blocks or a command I do not know, you can make this.
In Java Edition, the command to create a block of snow at 0, 64, 0 is
`/fill 0 64 0 0 64 0 minecraft:snow[layers:x]`, where x is how thick you want your snow to be (1-7). Therefore, to create a staircase, you can use a command like that and increment the x or z value in proportion to the variable x in layers. Such a command chain might look like-

```
/fill 0 64 0 0 64 0 minecraft:snow[layers:1]
/fill 0 64 1 0 64 1 minecraft:snow[layers:2]
/fill 0 64 2 0 64 2 minecraft:snow[layers:3]
/fill 0 64 3 0 64 3 minecraft:snow[layers:4]
/fill 0 64 4 0 64 4 minecraft:snow[layers:5]
/fill 0 64 5 0 64 5 minecraft:snow[layers:6]
/fill 0 64 6 0 64 6 minecraft:snow[layers:7]
```

which would create a path of snow 7 blocks long from 0, 64, 0 to 0, 64, 6, each block one step higher than the last.

Comment: Why not use `/setblock` instead of `/fill`?